# How to reset state when route changes?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having a problem with redux state. The state won't reset after route change.
I have a component with "ForgottenPassword ", when I type in email and click on "reminde password" there is alert with text "Email have been send" (if success) or "Error occured" (if email is incorrect). When I go to login component and then comeback to "ForgottenPassword" component the alert with text (success or error) is still there cause the state did not reset.
Is there a way to listen to route change and set state to initial so the success or error message would dissapear after route change?

```
const ForgottenPassword = (props: Props) => {
    const { loginUserLoading = false, forgottenPasswordAsync } = props;

    const t = useTranslationById();

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            email: "",
        },
        onSubmit: (values: ForgottenPasswordParams) => {
            forgottenPasswordAsync(values);
        },
    });

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (props.forgotPasswordLoadingSuccess) {
            formik.resetForm();
        }
    }, [props.forgotPasswordLoadingSuccess]);

    const handleSubmitButton = React.useCallback(() => formik.handleSubmit(), [formik]);

    return (
        <div className={styles["forgotten-password-form"]}>
            <div className={styles["forgotten-password-form__title"]}>{t("user-forgotten-password__title")}</div>
            <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <Input
                    label={t("user-login__email-label")}
                    placeholder={t("user-login__email-label")}
                    name="email"
                    type="text"
                />
                {props.forgotPasswordLoadingError && <div className={styles["forgotten-password-form__error"]}><FormattedMessage id="user-recover-password-error" /></div>}
                {props.forgotPasswordLoadingSuccess && <div className={styles["forgotten-password-form__success"]}><FormattedMessage id="user-recover-password-email-send" /></div>}
                <Button>
                   Remind password
                </Button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ForgottenPassword;
```

```
export const forgottenPassword = createAsyncAction(
    "FORGOTTEN_PASSWORD_REQUEST",
    "FORGOTTEN_PASSWORD_SUCCESS",
    "FORGOTTEN_PASSWORD_FAILURE"
)<void, any, ApiError>();
```

```
const reducer = (state: UserState = {}, action: UserAction) => {
    return produce(state, (draft) => {
        switch (action.type) {
     case getType(forgottenPassword.request):
                draft.forgottenPasswordLoading = true;
                break;
            case getType(forgottenPassword.success):
                draft.forgottenPasswordLoading = false;
                draft.forgottenPasswordLoadingSuccess = true;
                break;
            case getType(forgottenPassword.failure):
                draft.forgottenPasswordLoading = false;
                draft.forgottenPasswordLoadingError = action.payload;
                break;
        }
    });
};
```

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
    forgotPasswordLoading: selectForgotPasswordLoading(state),
    forgotPasswordLoadingSuccess: selectForgotPasswordLoadingSuccess(state),
    forgotPasswordLoadingError: selectForgotPasswordLoadingError(state),
    loginUserLoading: selectLoginUserLoading(state),
    loginUserLoadingError: selectLoginUserLoadingError(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) =>
    bindActionCreators(
        {
            forgottenPasswordAsync,
        },
        dispatch
    );

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ForgottenPassword);
```

```
export const selectForgotPasswordLoading = createSelector(selectState, (state) => state.forgottenPasswordLoading);
export const selectForgotPasswordLoadingSuccess = createSelector(selectState, (state) => state.forgottenPasswordLoadingSuccess);
export const selectForgotPasswordLoadingError = createSelector(selectState, (state) => state.forgottenPasswordLoadingError);
```

I am new here so sorry if I ask incorrectly.
The code is very complex and it is hard to paste only a sample of the code.

I was trying to do if else statemnt in Forgotten component but I figure out it won't work cause it is a problem that lies in redux, which I am starting to learn.

Comment: If you need the state to be local and not global, you may as well use it locally via `useReducer` from React (local by default) without using Redux (global by default). You are taking Redux and trying to remove it's feature when there is something easier at hand directly.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to reset the state when the route is changed you can use the `useEffect` hook in the role of a `componentWillUnmount` in the page that is getting destroyed (in this case I suppose it is `ForgottenPassword`).

You can manage the reset as you prefer. A solution can be adding an action to your redux state like `FORGOTTEN_PASSWORD_RESET` which resets the state, and then dispatching the action from the hook.

You can write:

```
//ForgottenPassword.jsx
const ForgottenPassword = () => {

 //existing code...

 React.useEffect(()=>{

  return () => {
   //This will be called only when the page is destroyed.
   reset() //reset your redux state here...
  }

 },[])

 return (
   //component's code...
 );

}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return ({
    reset: () => dispatch({ type: "FORGOTTEN_PASSWORD_RESET"}),
    //OTHER ACTIONS....
  })
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ForgottenPassword);
```

**TWO NOTES** on the code above:

1. Update your reducer to manage the new action, otherwise is useless. I've not fully understood how it works otherwise I would have updated myself
2. Usually, to keep the code "clean", the action should be stored in a separate file from the actual component and then imported.

Comment: what should I pass into dispatch( ) ?

Comment: Actually, it depends on how you build your redux mapDispatchToProps. For instance I usually create a dedicated method and use that method instead of directly dispatch. I updated the post with an example

Comment: Thank you for a very complex explanation. This project is badly written... I will try to implement your solution!